# Reordering menu items with Sonata Admin Bundle + Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, knpmenu

I have been working on a Symfony+SonataAdmin project, and we got stuck on Sonata KnpMenu ordering of elements.

First we used both Sonada Admin for insertion on the menu and `EventListeners` to add more menu items based on other routes we needed there. That worked fine. The problem is: when we used both native Admin and `EventListeners` to add options, their alphabetical order broke up, and options got separated on something like:

```
A option (EVTL)

E option (EVTL)

F option (EVTL)

B option (Adm)

C option (Adm)

D option (Adm)
```

Tried looking around a lot of places, and no one could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to achieve something similiar and I solve it like the example below (i do not know if there is beter solution, but that worked for me). I just created event subcriber:

```
class ConfigureMenuEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ConfigureMenuEvent::SIDEBAR => ['onConfigureMenu', 10]
        ];
    }

    public function onConfigureMenu(ConfigureMenuEvent $event)
    {
        $children = $event->getMenu()->getChildren();

        // todo some sorting operation with array

        $event->getMenu()->setChildren($children);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `$menu->reorderChildren([])`